# RNeo4j Error: Client error: (404) Not Found

Tags: r, neo4j

I am trying to query my neo4j graph which has already been made but I keep getting an error (Error: Client error: (404) Not Found) when I type the line cypher(graph, query).

The library seems to have installed fine. Also, I have used RNeo4j before without problems.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I'm using neo4j 2.3.1

Comment: What is the graph you are trying to connect to? Is it on http://localhost:7474/db/data or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I tried connecting to: http://localhost:7474/

Comment: Did you try connecting to: `http://localhost:7474/db/data` or just `http://localhost:7474/`? Does the graph require a username and password? You might need to connect to the first one and not the second one.

Comment: Just http://localhost:7474/ because that's how I did it last time, yes it requires a username and password which I entered too

Comment: What you have suggested has fixed my issue though, thank you very much, If you include add that as the answer rather than a comment then I can put it as problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting to the full path in your `startGraph()` function:

```
graph <- startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```

And enter a username and password if necessary!

Comment: How do I get the full path to a database?

Answer (score 0):

For the community edition: Always use /db/data/ When you start neo4j, you have to choose a database / directory.  R will connect to whatever database is currently mounted.